# How to make ListView's scroll slower when using smoothScrollToPosition() function?

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Scroll of my `ListView` is very fast when using `smoothScrollToPosition(int position)` function. I want to customize this and want to make it slower.

I tried set `android:fastscrollenabled="false"` and `setFriction(ViewConfiguration.getScrollFriction() * 5)` but it does not solve this problem.

Can someone help me?

Comment: refer [link](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

Comment: Sorry, I want to scroll slower, not smooth

Comment: ok so might be helpful that one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386096/speed-limit-for-scroll-view)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try

```
smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, offset, delay);
```

where `offset` is distance from the top and `delay` is the total amount of time to complete the scroll.

You could also set the delay based on the scroll amount, such as a larger delay for greater distance.