# How to stop auto scroll when it reached the bottom?

Tags: android

I've implemented really slow auto scroll for lyrics text in ScrollView:

```
private Handler timerHandler;
private Runnable timerRunnable;
private boolean isScrolling = false;
private TextView mSongTextTv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ....

 mSongTextTv.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Scroll Hendler
    timerHandler = new Handler();
    timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, 1);         // 1 is how many pixels you want it to scroll vertically by
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 40);     // 40 is how many milliseconds you want this thread to run
        }
    };
```

I can start and stop it simply by clicking on TextView:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
            ...
        case R.id.tv_song:
            if (!isScrolling) {
                timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
                isScrolling = true;
                Log.d("song tap", " is running = " + isScrolling);
            } else {
                timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
                isScrolling = false;
                Log.d("song tap", " is running = " + isScrolling);
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Also I'm using NestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeLisener to identify if the scroll reached the bottom. And then I use same method as in my onClick: timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable). I can see in logs that this method was called but it has no effect though! If I then scroll up autoscrolling continues again. Here's my onScrollChangeListener:

```
mScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {                
            View view = mScrollView.getChildAt(mScrollView.getChildCount()-1);
            int diff = (view.getBottom() - (mScrollView.getHeight() + mScrollView.getScrollY()));

            if (diff == 0 && isScrolling) {
                timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
                isScrolling = false;
                Log.d("song tap", " isScrolling = " + isScrolling);
                Log.d("onScrollChange", "reached bottom, diff = " + diff);
            }
        }
    });
```

So question is why does the call to removeCallbacks doesn't works in this situation (while it works in onClick) and how to stop executing of runnable after scroll reached bottom?

Comment: Just a suggestion - I recommend you use a `Scroller` for any scrolling related behaviour. It's API is more natural and easy to work with.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out this

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation on method [Handler.removeCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)) 
it removes only *pending* messages. Call following method:

```
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

to remove all messages and prevent further calls.

Comment: As well as Handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) does.

Answer (score 0):

onScrollChange invokes immediately after smoothScrollBy() and it removes any Callback but postDelayed() goes after that and does all the onScrollChange's work meaningless. So solution is:

```
timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 10);     // 10 is how many milliseconds you want this thread to run
            mScrollView.smoothScrollBy(0, 5);         // 5 is how many pixels you want it to scroll vertically by
        }
    };
```