# android -How to speed up scroll amount in scrollview

Tags: android

I've a scrollview in my activity . When I scroll down , it doesn't scroll much and I want to increase the the amount of scroll .

How can I do so?

Comment: As in, the number of items to scroll over or the speed at which you scroll?

Answer (score 1):

> Flinging is the type of scrolling that occurs when a user drags and lifts her finger quickly.

```
@Override
public void fling(int velocityY) {
int topVelocityY = (int) ((Math.min(Math.abs(velocityY), MAX_SCROLL_SPEED) ) * Math.signum(velocityY));
super.fling(topVelocityY);
}
```

I copied it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386096/speed-limit-for-scroll-view).