# auto scroll horizontalscroll view

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have horizontal scrollView in it views(Buttons) are added dynamically.

What I want is when activity starts horizontal scrollView scrolls automatically right to left.

I'm stuck with this problem. Anyone know how can I achieve this ?

Comment: override the ontouch and then calcualate how much the touched point moves, and from that, use scrollTo ?

Comment: oooops .. I dont want to touch the screen. It should automatically scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to scroll on the extreme right:

```
int w = myHorizontalScroll.getWidth();
myHorizontalScroll.scrollTo( w, 0 );
```

if you want to scroll on the extreme left:

```
 myHorizontalScroll.scrollTo( 0, 0 );
```

if you want have a smooth scroll you can use

```
myHorizontalScroll.smoothScrollTo( w, 0 );
```

Comment: i have done that :) But what i want is it will slowly scroll to right to left ... :(

Comment: @xitij check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/5193880/1166813 . also check the search function.