# GridView scroll

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, duration

I am using a gridview with many items.
I have a button in the activity that makes automatic scroll to the top of the gridview, using:

```
gridView.smoothScrollToPosition (0);
```

What I'm trying is to make the automatic scrolling is quite slow.
Is there any way to control the duration or speed of this scroll?

I'm looking for but can not find a simple way to do it

I sincerely appreciate any help

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

you can look at ther below sample, i hope it helps

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1515

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Android: HorizontalScrollView smoothScroll animation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193678/android-horizontalscrollview-smoothscroll-animation-time/5193880#5193880)

It uses a counter to scroll small increments at a time to give the appearance of scrolling slower.

Also (and I think a better solution) would be to subclass your gridview and override the smoothscrollby method which is called by the smoothscrollto and just set the duration in there: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.java#HorizontalScrollView.smoothScrollBy%28int%2Cint%29