# control the speed of scrolling in HorizontalScrollView in android

Tags: android, android-layout

hey guys I'm pretty inexpirienced in Android Development so I need your help :)

**The Issue**

I want the user to be able to see a list of images but as soon as they scroll I want them to be able to go the next image and not slide too much and skip images

**The Question**

So is there a way to make the scrolling speed slower or HorizontalScrollView is not the kind of view I want in order to achieve the thing I want?

**My Code**

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_0"
                android:id="@+id/dog"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_1"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_2" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/sample_3"/>

        </LinearLayout>





    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I'm writting what I ended up doing for anyone who wants to know :)

In the end the thing I was looking for was a viewPager which I implemented like [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found some information about slowing down Scroll view in other site [Android: HorizontalScrollView smoothScroll animation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193678/android-horizontalscrollview-smoothscroll-animation-time) (little google search :P).
But if you want do display alot of images, u could have problems with memory, in that situation maybe u should consider this [Managing Bitmap Memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

Comment: thank you very much for answering however it seems that the thing I'm looking for is overriding onScroll() method. If I manage to figure it out I'll post the answer here :)